# How to query 550,000 MySQL records in R?

Tags: mysql, r

I have a MySQL table which has around 550,000 records. When I try to retrieve all the records in R using this code:

```
connect <- dbConnect(drv, user=.....)
query1 <- paste("select * from db.table")
rs <- dbSendQuery(connect, query1)
myData <- fetch(rs, n = -1)
dbHasCompleted(rs)
dbClearResult(rs)
dbDisconnect(connect)
```

I only receive 367471 records.
However, when I run the exact same query in MySQL using the terminal window, I receive 546957 records.

I have `n = -1` in `fetch()` and also removed all limitations in R settings.

Does anybody know how to receive all records in R?

Comment: You could query them by chunks.

Comment: I would try this for example `fetch(rs, n = 550000)`.

Comment: Are you using RODBC library to connect to MySQL?

Comment: @pops I am using `library(RMySQL)` and `drv = dbDriver("MySQL")` to connect to MySQL.

Comment: @agstudy I tried `fetch(rs, n = 600000)` but it did not work. Still received 367471 records.

Comment: What do you get if you try `select count(*) from db.table` and `select firstColumn from db.table` (replace `firstColumn` with name of first column)?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Here are the results:

`mysql> select count(*) from db.table;

+----------+

| count(*) |

+----------+

|   546957 |

+----------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)`


`mysql> select firstColumn from db.table;`

printed a bunch of data then:

`546957 rows in set (0.19 sec)`

Comment: It seems to be able to grab a column ok so grab each column separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know why R does not retrieve all 546957 records from the table. However, as @Basile Starynkevitch and @G.Grothendieck suggested, I grabbed each column separately and then added them together to construct a table.